# Tint Bitmap with Paint?

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to create a function that tints a Bitmap,

this works...

```
 imgPaint = new Paint();

    imgPaint.setColorFilter(new LightingColorFilter(color,0));

//when image is being drawn
canvas.drawBitmap(img,matrix,imgPaint);
```

However, when the bitmap has to be drawn constantly (every frame) , I start to see screen lag, because this didn't occur before the color filter was set, I believe that it is applying the filter every time I need the canvas drawn.

Is there a way to apply the paint once to the bitmap and have it permanently changed?

Any help appreciated :)

Comment: Make sure you create the paint and colorfilter only one time, storing them inside variables to reuse them instead of recreating them every frame.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create a second bitmap and draw the first bitmap into it using the color filter. Then use the second bitmap for the high-volume rendering.

EDIT: Per request, here is code that would do this:

```
public Bitmap makeTintedBitmap(Bitmap src, int color) {
    Bitmap result = Bitmap.createBitmap(src.getWidth(), src.getHeight(), src.getConfig());
    Canvas c = new Canvas(result);
    Paint paint = new Paint();
    paint.setColorFilter(new LightingColorFilter(color,0));
    c.drawBitmap(src, 0, 0, paint);
    return result;
}
```

You would then call this method once to convert a bitmap to a tinted bitmap and save the result in an instance variable. You would then use the tinted bitmap directly (without a color filter) in your method that draws to `canvas`. (It would also be a good idea to pre-allocate the `Paint` object you will be using in the main draw method and save it in an instance variable as well, rather than allocating a new `Paint` on every draw.)

Comment: Thanks for the quick response Ted, how might I go about drawing the first bitmap to the second using the Paint?

Comment: Create a new bitmap (`Bitmap bmNew = Bitmap.createBitmap(bmOld.getWidth(), bmOld.getHeight(), bmOld.getConfig());`). Then create a new Canvas (`Canvas c = new Canvas(bmNew);`). Use the new Canvas to draw bmOld into bmNew using the Paint that has a color filter. That gives you a bitmap in bmNew that can be reused with a Paint that doesn't have a filter.

Comment: Can you provide some code that draws "bmOld into bmNew using the Paint that has a color filter"?